# Getting SSL error after downgrading to free dyno on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I recently downgraded one of my Heroku apps to a free dyno - as a result, the SSL was revoked (cos I was using the SSL provided with a paid dyno). Now, when I visit my site URL, it gives me this error: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I've edited my `production.rb` file to set: `config.force_ssl = false` and published that code, but it still redirects my site to `https` when I try to connect on `http`.

Now, to complicate things:

- This only applies to my custom domain - the .herokuapp.com domain works fine
- It works fine on incognito mode on both the custom domain and the herokuapp.com domain

I've tried clearing the cookies and cache (for the last 7 days) and it still didn't work :/

Any ideas what I can do?

**Edit:**

In case it helps, I am using Chrome on Windows 10

Comment: Are you using chrome?

Comment: Yes I am using Chrome. Could that be relevant?

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome) might help you.

Comment: That solved it! Thanks! If you put up a reference to that as an answer I can mark that as the best answer for this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are using Chrome, according to this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/881431), you need to follow these steps to stop Chrome from redirecting http:// to https://.

> Anon is right about STS, but there is a way to specifically delete your domain from the set. Go to chrome://net-internals/#hsts. Enter 3rdrevolution.com under Delete domain security policies and press the Delete button.
>
> Now go to chrome://settings/clearBrowserData, tick the box Cached images and files and press click the button Clear data.